# Converting a WS to WAP

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ive been trying to convert my asp.net website into a web application following the guide provided on msdn. However, ive run into a problem with some of my usercontrols that implements templating, getting the following error:

**'System.Web.UI.UserControl' does not have a public property named 'ContentTemplate'**

The codebehind clearly defines the template property like this which works fine in WS´s.

```
[TemplateContainer(typeof(ContentContainer))]
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
[TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)]
public ITemplate ContentTemplate { get; set; }
```

Update: I dont know how or why but some of these controls have managed to convert into WAP usercontrols (with the designer file added), and the problem then is that no asp controls i define within these templates can be found anymore in code behind.

The error:

**The name 'DropDownRoles' does not exist in the current context**

The markup:

```
<%@ Register src="~/Controls/Containers/ContainerFrame.ascx" tagname="ContainerFrame" tagprefix="uc" %>

<uc:ContainerFrame ID="ContainerFrame1" Title="Layout" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownRoles" runat="server" />
</ContentTemplate>
</uc:ContainerFrame>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Adding namespaces helped partially. 
Errors like "The name 'TextBoxUserName' does not exist in the current context" from codebehind of a page shows up randomly.
writing similar code in an empty WAP solution didnt give any errors, it feels very random.
When googling the problem the top solutions were to select the cs file as an "embedded resource" allowing it to compile but resulting in sideeffects. Shouldnt code-behind cs files be compiled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess at a namespace issue if it can't find it.

I have typically had problems like this with the page declarations but it is probably the same for user controls

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it's probably a namespace issue. Web Site Projects were intended to be kid's stuff, and namespaces are too complicated for kids. Using a Web Application Project means you've moved to the grown-up's table.

I recommend you start fully-qualifying your custom type names until you get the whole thing to build correctly, with the classes in the correct namespaces.